# How to use MSBuild command line to just link a project?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, linker

I just want to use msbuild command line option to relink a project. The default option is /t:build. When I change it to /t:link , the error is  MSB4057: The target "link" does not exist in the project
How can I enable linking for this solution ? 
     [echo] msbuild /nologo /m  /p:Configuration=" Release" /p:Platform="W
in32" /p:VisualStudioVersion="11.0" /t:link "../../XYZ.sln
"

Comment: @granadaCoder is right in general. For a .vcxproj, this might help [A guide to .vcxproj and .props file structure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/05/14/a-guide-to-vcxproj-and-props-file-structure.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing what the /t parameters is for.

In the below msbuild definition.

I can call any of these:

```
/t:AllTargetsWrapped
/t:CleanArtifactFolder
/t:BuildItUp
/t:CopyFilesToArtifactFolder
/t:RenameConfigurationFiles
```

or I can call no target, which will run "AllTargetsWrapped" because it is the default target.

Do you have a

```
    <Target Name="link">
```

in your code?

Below is the sample .proj definition to which I refer to above in my examples.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="AllTargetsWrapped">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- Always declare some kind of "base directory" and then work off of that in the majority of cases  -->
        <WorkingCheckout>.</WorkingCheckout>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="AllTargetsWrapped">

        <CallTarget Targets="CleanArtifactFolder" />
        <CallTarget Targets="BuildItUp" />
        <CallTarget Targets="CopyFilesToArtifactFolder" />
        <CallTarget Targets="RenameConfigurationFiles" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="CleanArtifactFolder"> 
        <Message Text="CleanArtifactFolder was called" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="BuildItUp">   
        <Message Text="BuildItUp was called" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="CopyFilesToArtifactFolder">   
        <Message Text="CopyFilesToArtifactFolder was called" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="RenameConfigurationFiles">    
        <Message Text="RenameConfigurationFiles was called" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cank use the [*BuildLink* target](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/01/11/vcbuild-vs-c-msbuild-on-the-command-line.aspx).